# calling multiple inheritance function is failing in python

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I am trying to call an multiple inheritance function in python but i am getting some error

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "kiran"
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 10
class Merge(A,B):
    def disp(self):
        print self.num

obj_var = Merge()
print obj_var.disp()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_calss_obj.py", line 12, in <module>
    print obj_var.disp()
  File "test_calss_obj.py", line 9, in disp
    print self.num
AttributeError: Merge instance has no attribute 'num'
```

Why does this error occurs and i need an ouput as prinited as 10

Comment: Just one of the __init__ functions will run. If Merge finds the __init__ in A, it runs it, and will not search for other __init__ functions. For more information: https://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/2014/python-tutorial-understanding-python-mro-class-search-path  One of the solution is to run the __init__ functions manually as it is in the answer of Susensio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the constructor for Merge:

```
class Merge(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
       A.__init__(self)
       B.__init__(self)
    def disp(self):
        print self.num
```